# ReactJs undefined error in Component and Reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm having a "no-undef" issue in my ReactJs app, the console says:

- Uncaught ReferenceError: equipment is not defined at Equipment line
  18 and line 21.
- Uncaught ReferenceError: identifier is not defined at Object../src/reducers/equipment.js (equipment.js:5)

This is the code I've written:

Component (..components/Equipment.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class Equipment extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.equipment.map(note => (
          <div className="card">
            <div className="card-header">
              Equipment
            </div>
            <div className="card-content">
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{equipment.identifier}</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{equipment.location}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button>edit</button><button>delete</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    equipment: state.equipment,
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Equipment);
```

Reducer (..reducers/equipment.js):

```
const initialState = [
  {
    equipment:  [
      identifier: "My Machine 1",
      location: "My Location 1"
    ]
  }
];


export default function equipment(state=initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Any idea of where's the error exactly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your initial state, should be object not array:

```
const initialState = {
  equipment: [{
    identifier: "My Machine 1",
    location: "My Location 1"
  }]
}
```

Also change `equipment`to `note` here:

```
<tr>
   <td>{note.identifier}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>{note.location}</td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! Now there's no error in the component but there's still an error in the reducer. Console says "Uncaught ReferenceError: identifier is not defined
    at Object../src/reducers/equipment.js (equipment.js:4)" and also "unexpected use of 'location' on line 5- no-restricted-globals". What can it be?

Comment: @Giulia my bad, i fixed it, please copy again

Comment: Thanks! it works! :) I suppose I should change the map function inside the component now, right?

Comment: Right, or if you need array, switch it to array. Look on my example it should work in old way

Comment: I get the error Uncaught TypeError: this.props.equipment.map is not a function

Comment: @Giulia try, I made 3rd edit on my answer, 2nd was not working example, 3rd (latest) should fix all errors. If not, problem is not with code you provided.

Comment: Sorry, the third edit does not show. There are just two edits.

Comment: Make sure that `equipment` has array type with one item inside reducer file, and `initialState` is simple object not an array

Answer (score 0):

Replace `equipment` with `note` inside Equipment.js

```
<tr>
   <td>{note.identifier}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>{note.location}</td>
</tr>
```